# How to jsx format supported in spacevim editor?

Tags: reactjs, vim, jsx, spacevim

My spacevim config file: init.toml

```
 [[layers]]
      name = "lang#javascript"
      auto_fix = true
      enable_flow_syntax = true
```

Comment: "spacevim" is not official vim. You can ask in their issue tracker to get supports. IMO, Using those kind of "distribution" is not recommended.

Comment: I got it, but spacevim is very very pretty :)

Comment: Vim [can](https://i.redd.it/eyqoxnew9xc21.png) [be](https://i.redd.it/890v8sr4kz211.png) [pretty](https://i.redd.it/onwgyub274231.png), too :)

Comment: I didn't like, vim official editor is very  colorful :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get Vim to support a certain syntax, it has to be given the relevant `.syntax` file. This can be done manually, or by installing a plugin that loads it for you.

I've never used SpaceVim (I used SpaceMacs once, a couple eons ago), but looking through its [documentation](https://spacevim.org/documentation/#custom-configuration), the `[[custom_plugins]]` section looks promising. I've mocked up an example to get you started:

```
[[custom_plugins]]
    name = "MaxMEllon/vim-jsx-pretty"
    merged = false
```

However, this method will only yield limited results. This will only get Vim to recognize the syntax and highlight accordingly; if you want full linting capability, it looks like [this GitHub user](https://github.com/barraponto/dotfiles/blob/d133a5190a7282b33f66a74570e282ac2db37622/home/.SpaceVim.d/autoload/bootstrap.vim) created a script to modify the [`bootstrap#after` section](https://spacevim.org/documentation/#bootstrap-functions) of SpaceVim to use ESLint, which supports JSX. Note that you have to have ESLint installed for that to work.

For anything this "extreme", it looks like modifying the `bootstrap.vim` file is the only real way to go. In case you ever want to do further customization outside of SpaceVim defaults, I highly recommend getting Vim/neovim and installing the plugins yourself.

Comment: Achievement unlocked: search for something online, find a link to yourself.

Comment: Just want to let you know, this plugin has been included into `lang#typescript` layer  now.